# Spark 2.0 sql threw exception when upgrade to Spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can't find docs anywhere about Spark 2.3 backward compatibility

Currently there is a few Spark query can successfully run in Spark 2.0 but got following exception in Spark 2.3. It seems related to nested query in the same table but not sure why define alias didn't resolve it.

```
val dataTable = spark.sql("select * from mydb.mytable a where a.version_no in (select cast(max(cast(b.version_no as int)) as string) as version_no from mydb.mytable b)")
val lastUpdateDate = dataTable.select("value").where(dataTable("item") <=> "lastUpdateDate").rdd.map(_.getString(0)).toLocalIterator.toList.head
```

The exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) item#15 missing from value#16 in oper
!Filter (item#15 <=> lastUpdateDate)                                                                                                
+- AnalysisBarrier                                                                                                            
  +- Project [value#16]                                                                                                   
     +- Project [item#15, value#16, description#17, version_no#18, name#19, date#20]                       
        +- Filter version_no#18 IN (list#14 [])                                                                           
           :  +- Aggregate [cast(max(cast(version_no#24 as int)) as string) AS version_no#13]                             
           :     +- SubqueryAlias b                                                                                       
           :        +- SubqueryAlias mytable                                                          
           :           +- HiveTableRelation `mydb`.`mytable`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerd
]                                                                                                                             
           +- SubqueryAlias a                                                                                             
              +- SubqueryAlias mytable                                                                
                 +- HiveTableRelation `mydb`.`mytable`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde, [it
```

Comment: You only select the ``value`` field then you try to filter on another field (``item``). Cannot work and this makes sense. You need to filter before selecting the ``value`` column

Comment: @baitmbarek thanks. Then where the `filter` should be `before` the value selection?

Comment: Try this :
``val lastUpdateDate = dataTable.where(dataTable("item") <=> "lastUpdateDate").select("value").rdd.map(_.getString(0)).first``

Comment: @baitmbarek that works, much appreciated! So Spark SQL should written in the opposite order than regular SQL, filter code come first (where clause) then project (select). Please put your solution as answer I will close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert filter and projection in your code.

Try this :

```
val lastUpdateDate = dataTable.where(dataTable("item") <=> "lastUpdateDate").select("value").rdd.map(_.getString(0)).first
```